# What is more performant when using string.Format with many args: string or StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

Does using `string.Format` like this:

```
string.Format(txt, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4,...)
```

is the same as saying `txt+=args;` thus it creates new object every time it append a new string from the args list? and better using `StringBuilder.Format` ?

Comment: Why don't you [try to race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?

Comment: You mean trying something like this: `string st = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++)
            {
                st += "dop ";            }` It's damn fast! though it's disastrous loop, why? because it created  9000 objects. how to know if `StringBuilder.Format` propagate objects by testing?!

Comment: Just look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,691a34e179b91fdb) first when you have a question like this.  StringBuilderCache ought to convince you that the framework code doesn't suck and doesn't need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment above means that you should test your performances in your environment. Use a Stopwatch instance, create a loop that runs over the string.Format and StringBuilder.AppendFormat for at least one hundred thousands times and then measure the value in the Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds. This will roughly give you an idea of the differences.

In mine environment the two approaches are pretty identical. The difference on a 100000 loop is 2/3 milliseconds advantage for StringBuilder but the morale is:

**DO NOT DO MICROOPTIMIZATIONS**

(unless you have absolutely clear that the result worth the effort).

Sample:

```
string s1 = "Argument 1";
string s2 = "Argument 2";
string s3 = "Argument 3";
string s4 = "Argument 4";
string s5 = "Argument 5";
string s6 = "Argument 6";
string s7 = "Argument 7";
string s8 = "Argument 8";
string s9 = "Argument 9";

string result = string.Empty;
object[] data = new object[] { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9 };
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for(int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
    result = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8}", data);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
{
    sb.Length = 0;
    sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8}", data);
    result = sb.ToString();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Is there a way to see objects created by `string +=` in runtime?

Comment: Not clear. What objects are you talking about? strings are immutable so, everytime you call the += operator a new string is created with the previous value of your variable plus the added string. Then the new string is assigned to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use just string format, use string.Format.
If you use a lot concatenation of strings and/or string forms, use StringBuilder.

Check this out:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306822

Answer (score 0):

String.Format uses a StringBuilder in its implementation, So you cannot say which one is better.